# Why is the navigation bar extended across the width of the mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, interface

**EDIT the question by adding more code to the beginning of the code**
Why is the navigation bar extended across the width of the mobile device?
Sorry for the way I write, I have to make use of the translator.
Hello, I have this form on a website with a price list. Well, when you see it on the mobile device, all the content is extended to the right, forcing you to scroll, expanding the screen, instead of looking at it, paragraph by paragraph down. I have two identical pages, the other works perfectly, because I do not have the "price styles" that I show in the code, so I think the problem will come from here and more specifically from the navigation bar, because in the device it is the which is seen to extend across. I do not know why on this page the navigation bar extends, in particular it extends to the width is the button of the links, being even of another color that on the other page. What can this error be caused? I do not know if I should show the other code, but I uploaded it to the server and I see the error without the other styles.

```css
/* new styles*/
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}


.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0; 
 margin-top: 21px;
 border-top: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {outline: 0;}

#container-2{
 background-color: #EBB250;
}
.home-section {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
 z-index:120;
 
}
.home-section2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}

.inner-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}


.home-section.nopadd-bot {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.section-heading h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section-heading p {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
}
@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
 
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    } 
    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 #navigation {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 .site-logo{
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  float:none;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  color: #eee;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;

 }
 .navbar-header {
  margin-top:-40px;
  padding:0;
 }
 .navbar-header button {
  background: #111;
 }
 
 .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .nav {
  background: #444;
 }
 
 .service-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .team-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 
 form#contact-form {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .xs-marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }
 
 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.navbar .navbar-custom {
 padding: 0;
}
    
    
    
/* estilos del formulario*/
@media  only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) 
{
    .form-container {
      padding: 5%;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 9px solid #f2f2f2;            
      max-width: 520px;
      margin: auto;
    }

}

h1, p 
{
  text-align: center;
}

input, textarea , button
{
  width: 100%;
}    
textarea
{
  height: 200px;
}
button{
 background-color: #3bbec0 !important;
}

/* estilos de la pagina */

@import "grid.css";
@import "reset.css";
@import "font-awesome.css";
@import "superfish.css";

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Denk+One);

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic);
html {
    width: auto;

}
a[href^="tel:"] {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #908e8e;
    font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#container .column {
    /*position: relative !important;*/
    padding-top: 0px !important ;
  }

#works{
 background-color: #A4EB8F;
 padding-top: 10px ;
 padding-bottom: 30px ;
 
}
#works p{
 font-size: 20px ;
}

#informacion h2{
    padding-top: 10px ;
}

.ic {
 border:0;
 float:right;
 background:#fff;
 color:#f00;
 width:50%;
 line-height:10px;
 font-size:10px;
 margin:-220% 0 0 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0
}

strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}

address {
    font-style: normal;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.p1 {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

input {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #474343;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Denk One', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-top: 83px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2.head1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    padding-top: 99px;
}

h3  {
    padding-top: 69px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font: 30px/43px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.page1 h3 {
    padding-top: 98px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 34px;
}

h4.head1 {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4.head2 {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list .count {
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 30px/48px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 49px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background-color: #25952a;
}

.list li {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list li+li {
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.list1 {
    margin-top: -3px;
}

.list1 li {
    position: relative;
}

.list1 li+li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.list1 li a:after {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c7c6c6;
    height: 1px;
}

.list1 li a:hover:after {
    background-color: #25952a;
    width: 0;
}

.list2  {
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.list2 li {
    background: url(../img/dots.png) 0 72% repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list2 li+li {
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.list2 .prod {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.list2 .price {
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.list2  {
    overflow: hidden;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.btn  {
    margin-top: 73px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 22px 62px 24px;
    background-color: #25952a /*#3da9b6*/;
    font: bold 30px/40px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.link1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font: 24px/26px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: #3b3a3a;
}

.paeg1 .link1 {
    margin-top: 14px;
}

.mb__0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.m0 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.pad0 {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.img_inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.fleft {
    float: left;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.page1 .fleft {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.rel {
    position: relative;
}


.oh {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fright {
    float: right !important;
}
.upp {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.alright {
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper, .extra_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear {
    float: none !important;
    clear: both;
}

.oh {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.page1 header h1{
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.content {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.page1 .content {
    padding-bottom: 36px;
}

.text1 {
    color: #6a6a6a;
    margin-top: -21px;
    font: 20px/22px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.ban_img {
    margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.link22{
    color: #844007;
}

.links a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.links li+li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: #79c4ca;
    font: 36px/43px 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.box_bot  {
    padding-top: 63px;
    padding-bottom: 69px;
}

.box_bot span {
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.block1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block1+.block1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.sep__1 {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.sep__2 {
    padding-top: 77px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.sep__3 {
    height: 92px;
}
.color1 {
    color: #25952a/*#3da9b6*/;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.color1 a:hover, a.color1:hover {
    color: #474343;
}

.color2 {
    color: #474343;
}

.td_und {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.top {
    margin-bottom: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../images/totop.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 82px;
    height: 82px;
    transition: 0s ease;
    -o-transition: 0s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0s ease;
}

.top:hover {
    background-position: right 0;
}

.copy {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.sub_copy {
    margin-top: -4px;
}

body {
    min-width: 1200px;
  }
  .container_12 {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1200px;
  }
  .grid_1,
  .grid_2,
  .grid_3,
  .grid_4,
  .grid_5,
  .grid_6,
  .grid_7,
  .grid_8,
  .grid_9,
  .grid_10,
  .grid_11,
  .grid_12 {
      display:inline;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-right: 15px;
      
  }
  .grid_4 li{
      font-size: 16px;
  }

  .grid_4 p{
    font-size: 16px;
}
  
  .push_1, .pull_1,
  .push_2, .pull_2,
  .push_3, .pull_3,
  .push_4, .pull_4,
  .push_5, .pull_5,
  .push_6, .pull_6,
  .push_7, .pull_7,
  .push_8, .pull_8,
  .push_9, .pull_9,
  .push_10, .pull_10,
  .push_11, .pull_11,
  .push_12, .pull_12 {
      position:relative;
  }
  .alpha {
      margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  .omega {
      margin-right: 0;
  }
  .container_12 .grid_4 {
      width:370px;
  }
   
  .clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Agrochema</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700'>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai|Cormorant+Upright|Farsan" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">

 <div id="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="site-logo">
       <img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active">
         <a href="../index.html">Casa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="../galerias.html#about">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../galerias.html">Servicios</a></li>
         <a href="#works">Contacto</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
       <h2 class="h-bold">Nues</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <section class="content">
   <div class="ic"></div>
   <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_8">
     <h4 class="head1">Revise nuestros precios</h4>
     <div class="grid_4 alpha">
      <p class="color1">Ponemos a su servicio nuestra larga experiencia y los materiales de primeras marcas. La mayor calidad, al menor precio...</p>
      <ul class="list2">
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Mantenimiento mensual</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">Desde 50€</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Mantenimiento de comunidades</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de cesped *</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cesped artificial</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidado de setos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidado de rosales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantas ornamentales </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Diseño de jardines</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">Variable...</div>
       </li>

       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>(*)En la plantación de césped natural, le ofrecemos un mes de mantenimiento gratuito, y asegurar su agarre y proliferación.</a>
        </div>
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="grid_4 omega">
      <p class="color1">Limpieza y desbroce de fincas. Trabajos de campo, especialistas en huerta ecologica.</p>
      <ul class="list2">
       <br>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Sembramos su huerta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Cuidamos su huerta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Arado de fincas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Rotulamos las fincas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de viñedos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Siembras ecologicas</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="prod">
         <a>Plantacion de frutales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
    <p class="color1">
      <a href="#">Venta de leña, amplia variedad...</a>
     </p>
     <br>
     <p class="color1">
      <a href="#">Servicio de portes </a>
     </p>
     <p class="p1">En Agrochema</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="sep__2"></div>
   <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Trabajos en madera</h3>
     <ul class="list2">
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Vallados en madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>

      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Porches de madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Pèrgolas de madera</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Cabañas para herramienta</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>Casetas de animales</a>
       </div>
       <div class="price">10 a 15€ h.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="prod">
        <a>(*)Toda la madera que utilizamos es de primera calidad, tratada para aguantar el paso de los años y las inclemencias
         meteorológicas.
        </a>
       </div>
       <!--<div class="price">$80,22</div>-->
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Nuestro compromiso</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a>Fiabilidad, innovación y determinación son los valores sobre los que se fundamenta nuestra empresa, el trabajo diario,
        las relaciones con los clientes y en la forma de hacer nuestro trabajo. Los equipos de trabajo nos unen, garantizando
        así que conocimientos y experiencias se compartan y se apliquen en toda las labores; todo ello redunda en nuestros
        clientes. Estos valores son los que nos orientan a implementar constantes mejoras en nuestros productos y a ofrecer
        un buen servicio a nuestros clientes. Viviendo como nuestros estos valores, logramos nuestros objetivos, facilitando
        la tarea de nuestros clientes, trabajadores y al conjunto del sector.
       </a>
      </li>
      <!--<li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc... </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc.... </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc...</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc... </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc...</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a>Expecialistas en jardineria, podas, etc...</a>
      </li>-->
     </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">
     <h3>Nuestros objetivos</h3>
     <p>Nuestro objetivo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </section>
 <section id="works">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="informacion">
     <p>05400 Arenas de San Pedro</p>
     <p>(Avila)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="form_container">
     <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
     <h5>
      Contacte conmigo
     </h5>
     <form method="post" id="reused_form">
      <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre...">
      <label for="email">Email :</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Correo electronico...">
      <label for="message">Mensage:</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="Message" rows="10" maxlength="6000" required></textarea>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMA0sUAAAAALFN5W-V06LOOeWEUf7T2hVlt5Yu"></div>
      <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>

     </form>
     <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
      <h3>¡¡ El mensaje se envió con éxito...!!</h3>
      <p>Nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto. </p>
     </div>
     <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
      <h3>Error</h3>Lo sentimos, hubo un error al enviar su formulario.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="contact" class="home-section nopadd-bot color-dark bg-gray text-center"> 
 </section>
 <footer>
  <div id="container">
   <div class="column col-md-4">
   </div>
   <div class="column col-md-4">   
   </div>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to modify this to get it exactly how you want it, but the issue seems to be coming from the widths set on the body and on .container_12.

You can set the body to a max-width, and remove the width from .container_12:

```
body {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
  .container_12 {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
  }
```

This is unless you want the body to go 100%, then it will needed to be edited further as needed.

Also, your media query is referencing the class .form_container, but the HTML has it as the ID #form_container.

Comment: Thank you @wpalmes . Solve the problems that I indicated and put your proposal, but it does not work. I do not know what else to do, I've been with this problem for 3 days. Later in answering because I try to add more code from another page, ( extensive) but the problem must be in this, since the other page works perfectly. I will continue trying the solution, it is a lot of time that I have been employed in this web.
Thanks for the support.   The problem could be the navigation bar, on the other page the navigation bar is extended, I edit the code and add what part of the navigation bar

Comment: I EDIT the question adding more code to the beginning of the code I hope it helps in something. The other page works with this code, but the navigation bar extends to the right, even though the content is maintained. It leaves empty the right part of the screen, being able to do scroll, in spite of as I say, it does not have content.

Comment: I could be missing something, but whenever I scale it down to under 768px for the media query, the body is still set at a min-width of 1200px and the navigation bar is still extending 100% of that.  When I run the code snippet in full screen and inspect with Google Chrome, editing those settings allow it to scale on the page better on my end.

Comment: Thanks, @ wpalmes I can not ask more questions in the next three days. I have created a question in Spanish, there I put it with another code, if you want you can review. [My question in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144822/por-que-se-la-barra-de-navegaci%C3%B3n-me-crea-un-vaci%C3%B3)
Thanks for your support.